# can i improve this "regex"?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string:

```
const myString = '"{{ some text here }}"'
```

I want to remove the quotes before `{{` and after `}}`. I can do:

```
myString.replace('"{{', '{{').replace('}}"', '}}')
```

But I'm wondering if there is a better way to achieve this without calling replace twice?

Does anyone can let me know if there is a better way and explain?

http://jsbin.com/xafovamihi/edit?js,console

Comment: (Tip: calling `.replace()` with a string only replaces the first instance. This might be what you want, of course.)

Comment: How better? Faster? Better readable? More robust?

Comment: @Julian yes, more readable

Comment: I doesn't get more readable than that.

Comment: if the quotes will always be the first and last positions within the string, then you should slice the string instead. `str.slice(1, -1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a regex with an alternation group where you can capture `{{` and `}}` into Group 1 and 2 respectively and replace with the backreferences only:

```js
var myString = '"{{ some text here }}"';
console.log(myString.replace(/"({{)|(}})"/g, '$1$2'))
```

**Details**:

- `"({{)` - matches `"` and captures `{{` into Group 1
- `|`  - or
- `(}})"` - captures `}}` into Group 2 and matches `"`

Since the replacement backreferences, when referencing a group that did not participate in the match, are initialized with an empty string, this `$1$2` replacement will work properly all the time.

The global modifier `/g` will ensure all matches are replaced.

Comment: offtopic: how did you learn regex and how did you get so good?

Comment: Simple: I joined SO and have been answering regex questions for 3 years on end without missing a single day.

Comment: Wiktor, why is it so hard to catch that second quotation? Consider following regex `"(?={{)|(?!}})"`. That second one (negative lookahead) marks every quotation even without curly bracket as a neighbour. How to deal with it? Is it possible to fix it just with lookaheads?

Comment: @Kinduser: JS regex engine does not support a lookbehind that you need to properly get that quote. The `(?!}})"` pattern is the same as `"` because `"` is not a start of the `}}` substring (and it is exactly what the `(?!}})"` pattern means: match any `"` that does not start a `}}` sequence).

Comment: Thank you, Wiktor.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way would be to combine the two patterns into one match using regex OR, so you get `/"{{|}}"/g`

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use regex to find `{{` with  `}}` and any text between?

```js
const myString = '"{{ some text here }}"',
      reg = /{{.*?}}/;
console.log(myString.match(reg)[0]);
```